# CUDA: minimize bank conflict for large data type

Tags: c++, memory, cuda, gpu, nvidia

32 banks are mapped to 32 consecutive words. I wonder if a data type is large, say

```cpp
struct foo{
    float data[n];
};

__global__
void kernel(foo* d_ptr){
    __shared__ foo sh_data[number_threads_block];
    int tid = threadIdx.x;
    sh_data[tid] = d_ptr[tid + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x];
    __syncthreads();

    sh_data[tid] = ...
}
```

where n are chosen to be 8 (or 16, 32). Then when we access sh_data[tid], if I get it right, there will be 8 (or 16, 32) bank conflictions.

If this is the case, are there any techniques which can minimise the bank conflictions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You effectively have an array of structures (AoS).  This is canonically bad for GPU programming.  You could use the standard AoS->SoA data reorganization methodology to fix the access, so that adjacent threads are accessing adjacent elements (which will prevent bank conflicts).
2. Load the data in larger chunks, e.g. reorganize your structure so that it can represent 4 `float4` quantities rather than `16` `float` quantities.  The compiler may be able to organize the load into `float4` loads, which will reduce bank conflicts.   You could even use a union in the structure if you really need both access methods.

Based on the question in the comments, let's diagram this second case out.  For 16 `float` quantities per structure, whether stored as an array of `float` or an array of `float4`, the storage pattern would be like this:

```
(key: SXY  = float[Y] in Structure S[X], BX == Bank X)
B00 B01 B02 B03 B04 B05 B06 B07 B08 B09 B10 B11 B12 B13 B14 B15 B16 B17 B18 B19 B20 B21 B22 B23 B24 B25 B26 B27 B28 B29 B30 B31
S00 S01 S02 S03 S04 S05 S06 S07 S08 S09 S0A S0B S0C S0D S0E S0F S10 S11 S12 S13 S14 S15 S16 S17 S18 S19 S1A S1B S1C S1D S1E S1F
S20 S21 S22 S23 S24 S25 S26 S27 S28 S29 S2A S2B S2C S2D S2E S2F S30 S31 S32 S33 S34 S35 S36 S37 S38 S39 S3A S3B S3C S3D S3E S3F
S40 S41 S24 S43 S44 S45 S46 S47 S48 S49 S4A S4B S4C S4D S4E S4F S50 S51 S52 S53 S54 S55 S56 S57 S58 S59 S5A S5B S5C S5D S5E S5F
...
```

Now, suppose our storage per thread is like this:

```
const int n = 16;
struct foo{
    float data[n];
};
```

And our "load" operation looks like this:

```
sh_data[tid] = ...
```

The compiler [cannot load 16x4 bytes in a single instruction per thread](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#device-memory-accesses) so it will break the above load operation into a sequence of requests.  *I think* this sequence will either be a loop loading `float` quantities or a loop loading bytes (i.e. a `memcpy`).  Let's assume it loads `float` quantities.  Therefore the first iteration of said loop will request `S00`, `S10`, `S20`, `S30` ... across the warp.  This is only 1 `float` per thread, so across the warp it is 128 bytes, so in theory it could be serviced in a single transaction.  But `S00`, `S20`, `S40`, ... are in the same bank, and likewise `S10`, `S30`, `S50`, ... are all in the same bank, so we will have a 16-way bank conflict, just as you predicted in your question.

Now, suppose our storage per thread is like this:

```
const int n = 16;
struct foo{
    float4 data[n/4];
};
```

And our "load" operation looks like this:

```
sh_data[tid] = ...
```

Once again, the compiler cannot load 16x4 bytes in a single instruction per thread.  So it must break up the transfer.  If, in this case, we can coax the compiler into loading a `float4` per thread, then the first loop iteration will attempt to load S00-S03 for thread 0, S10-S13 for thread 1, etc.  This load is now 512 bytes instead of 128 bytes.  So the single warp read instruction for that loop iteration will be broken up into 4 shared memory transactions.  The first transaction will consist of a load request for S00-S03, S10-S13, S20-S23, S30-S33, S40-S43, S50-S53, S60-S63, S70-S73.  If we inspect this on the above diagram, we see that we have converted the previous sequence involving 16-way bank conflicts per loop iteration/transaction to a new sequence involving 4-way bank conflicts per loop iteration/transaction.  We have the same number of 128-byte transactions going to shared memory, but each transaction is now burdened with a 4-way bank conflict instead of a 16-way bank conflict.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I don't get the second point, if there are 4 float4 in a class foo, then those 32 banks still can only serve two instance of class foo simultaneously (in a warp), meaning there will be 16 way bank conflict?

Comment: I've added an explanation of what I had in mind to my answer.  This second approach only *reduces* bank conflicts, it does not eliminate them.  Using the first approach may allow you to *eliminate* bank conflicts through data reorganization.  The second approach assumes we can "coax" the compiler into the desired `float4` load pattern.  With sufficient effort, it should be possible.  Finally, you can use the profiler to immediately report bank conflicts, eg. via the `shared_replay_overhead` [metric](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html#metrics-reference).